# Iterator retrieve first value and place it back on the same iterator

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have the following scenario: I have an existing iterator `Iterator<String> it` and I iterate over its head (say first k elements, which are flagged elements, i.e. they start with '*' ). The only way to know that the flagged elements are over, is by noticing that the (k+1)th element is not flagged.

The problem is that if I do that, the iterator `it` will not provide me the first value anymore on the next call to `next()`.

I want to pass this iterator to a method as it's only argument and I would like to avoid changing its signarture and it implementation. I know I could do this:

```
   public void methodAcceptingIterator(Iterator<String> it) //current signature

   //change it to 

  public void methodAcceptingIterator(String firstElement, Iterator<String> it)
```

But this looks like a workarround/hack decreasing the elegance and generality of the code, so I don't want to this.

Any ideas how I could solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create your own Iterator implementation which stores the `firstElement` and uses the existing iterator as an underlying Iterator to delegate the requests for the rest of the elements to.

Something like:

```
  public class IteratorMissingFirst<E> implements Iterator<E>{

private Iterator<E> underlyingIterator;
private E firstElement;
private boolean firstElOffered;

public IteratorMissingFirst(E firstElement, Iterator<E> it){
    //initialize all the instance vars
}

public boolean hasNext(){
    if(!firstElOffered && firstElement != null){
            return true;
    }
    else{
        return underlyingIterator.hasNext();
    }
}

public E next(){
    if(!firstElOffered){
        firstElOffered = true;
        return firstElement;
    }
    else return underlyingIterator.next();
}

public void remove(){

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Guava's [PeekingIterator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#peekingIterator%28java.util.Iterator%29) (link contains the javadoc for a static method which, given an `Iterator`, will return a wrapping `PeekingIterator`). That includes a method `T peek()` which shows you the next element without advancing to it.

Comment: Interesting iterator !Didn't know about it! this means I can use it outside my method the iterator and preserve the same signature. The problem is that I don't have control over the underlying iterator. It's passed to my application by the framework :(

Comment: Depending on how this thing works, this might be a solution. The think is that the underlying it iterates over a huge data set, stored on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have `methodAcceptingIterator` store the first element it gets out of the iterator in a variable?  Or -- in a pinch -- just copy the contents of the `Iterator` into an `ArrayList` at the beginning of your method; now you can revisit elements as often as you like.

Comment: I can't use an ArrayList because this iterator has a large number of values. It wouldn't fit in main memory.

Comment: It's still not really clear what you want to do with this first element, and why you can't just store it in a variable as the first step of your method.

Comment: I could certainly do that, but this means modifying the implementation of methodAcceptingIterator

Comment: ...Yes.  Yes, it does.  I can't imagine any solution that doesn't involve modifying the implementation of `methodAcceptingIterator`, including the other solutions suggested above.  But it wouldn't change the signature, which is about as good as you can probably get.

Answer (score 0):

With Guava, you can implement Razvan's solution in an easier way by using some methods from the `Iterables` class:

```
Iterators.concat(Iterators.singletonIterator(firstElement), it)
```

This gives you an iterator working similar to `IteratorMissingFirst`, and it's easy to extend if you need to look at more than one element in front (but it creates two objects instead of only one).